# Geolocation database of beaches

Tags: google-maps, database, geolocation

Anyone know where or how to obtain a database of worldwide beaches?

Required fields are:

- name
- latitude
- longitude
- coastline aspect (if possible)

Alternatively, is there a way to query Google Maps to find the closest beaches to a given geolocation?

Comment: I'm not sure that "beach" is common world-wide. Those things called "beach" in the UK would be "rocks" in Australia. Anyway, perhaps http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dbeach and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API might be suitable if you are OK with the OdBL that Open Street Map uses.

Comment: Thanks @BradHards, OpenStreetMap looks like a great resource. The licence is fine - happy to give credit to its contributors. If you make this an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BradHards those things called "beach" in the UK would be laughed out of Australia

Comment: [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/features/) has a selection of physical vector data, such as ocean coastlines and lakes.

Answer (score 4):

maybe this can help you (shorelines): http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html

they have both ESRI shapefile format or binary format

Comment: Thanks @A.R, looks perfect for establishing the coastline aspect. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that "beach" is common world-wide. Those things called "beach" in the UK would be "rocks" in Australia.

Anyway, perhaps [wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:natural%3Dbeach](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3anatural=beach) and [wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) might be suitable if you are OK with the [ODbL](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Open_Database_License) that Open Street Map uses.

Note that ODbL requires more than just attribution. A simple version of the rights and responsibilities is at http://opendatacommons.org/licenses/odbl/summary/

Answer (score 2):

For Uk
Bathing Waters Quality at Designated Beaches, a shapefile is available to download from the Environment Agency at:

http://www.geostore.com/environment-agency/WebStore?xml=environment-agency/xml/ogcDataDownload.xml

This may be of help for the UK.

Something on this site may be of use for the US but I have no reason to use it so dont know:
http://www.fws.gov/gis/data/national/index.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Gerald, great resources but unfortunately I need the rest of the world too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try looking at the Places API and try querying on one of the second places types (https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types#table2). Beaches could possibly be in the 'natural_feature' category but that still doesn't get around the language problem. Good Luck.

I believe the UK English word for beach is "Frigidpebble" ;-P